# How to compile a CGAL program in ubuntu terminal

Tags: c++, linux, compilation, compiler-errors, cgal

I am sorry for the possibly stupid question but I am really a noob in programming and linux.
I have copied a program from the examples of CGAL and I am trying to compile it with the terminal. I am using the order :

g++ convex_hull.cpp -o convex_hull

which I found on the internet, but the errors are many, and I suspect from what I read that it does not recognise the cgal orders in it. It says things like:

"    undefined reference to `CGAL::assertion_fail(char const*, char const*, int, char const*)'     "   etc.

Do you have any idea how to fix this?

Note: I have installed cgal successfully, so I do not think this is the problem.

Comment: As with every library you need to add the library and - if needed - the include path. Something like: `g++ convex_hull.cpp -lCGAL -I/usr/local/include -o convex_hull`

Comment: Thank you! what is the include path? it did not work only with adding -lCGAL but the errors are significantly fewer. Now it founds undefined references connected to "Gmpq" things

Comment: Where the CGAL headers are installed depends on the system and on the package you installed. But if you installed it with `apt-get` then imho it most likely it is `/usr/local/include` but I don't know it by heart. Anyway, does it still complain about `undefined reference to CGAL::assertion_fail(char const*, char const*, int, char const*)` or is it another error now?

Comment: I included the gmp library with the same way and it worked! Thanks a lot!!

Comment: For completeness, I wrote:     g++ convex_hull.cpp -lCGAL -lgmp -o convex_hull

Comment: You might think about using something like _cmake_ because it is able to find many common libraries (including CGAL, GMP, ....) and their include paths. At least for larger projects with many libraries it is really helpful.

Comment: @t.niese If you install with apt-get, then the headers are in /usr/include and you do **not** need any `-I` flag.

Comment: http://doc.cgal.org/latest/Manual/installation.html#title34 advertises a couple scripts that automatically generate a CMakeLists.txt for you.

Comment: Having encountered the same error, `g++ cgaltest.cpp -lCGAL -o cgaltest` worked for me as well as `g++ cgaltest.cpp -lCGAL -lgmp -o cgaltest2`. I had `libcgal-dev` installed.

Answer (score 1):

try it
 g++ filename -lCGAL -gmp
 mesh.txt